# Real Analysis. Integration. Problem in solution.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f,g:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous and $p$ integrable with $p(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove that if
>   $$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)p(x)\mathrm{d}x = f(a)\int\limits_{a}^{b}p(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
>   then there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = f(a)$.

I tried assume that $f(x) > f(a)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, after, assume that $f(x) < f(a)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. But applying the integral in $f(x)p(x) > f(a)p(x)$ and $f(x)p(x) < f(a)p(x)$, I'll get non-strict inequalities.

Any idea?

Comment: This looks familiar, what book is this from?

Comment: @Wolfy "Análise Real Vol 1 - Elon Lages Lima"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\displaystyle\int_a^bg(x)p(x)\,dx=0$ with $g$ continuous, you get from $p>0$ that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $g(c)=0$. Otherwise, the integral cannot be zero.

Now take $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)$.